# Is it permissible to believe that a protective barrier protects you?

Tags: shirk

So as we know believing that the nazar  eye ,,protects" you is shirk. But my question is when you are for example in a boat and you see a shark drawing near you, so you use a protective barrier (crates for example) so the shark is less likely to kill you. Now, does believing the crates will protect you from the shark shirk?

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, as a purely monotheistic religion, we rely on Allah for everything and believe he is the perfect, most powerful being. So anything that happens, he has allowed/willed it, and anything that doesn't happen, he didn't allow/will it regardless of what anyone else has willed.

> And they say, “We obey,” but when they leave you, a group of them would spend the night contradicting what they said. Allah records all their schemes. So turn away from them, and put your trust in Allah. And Allah is sufficient as a Trustee of Affairs.
>
> <sup>[Quran 4:81](https://quran.com/4/81)</sup>

> But you cannot will ˹to do so˺ unless Allah wills. Indeed, Allah is All-Knowing, All-Wise.
>
> <sup>[Quran 76:30](https://quran.com/76/30)</sup>

> Say, “Nothing will ever befall us except what Allah has destined for us. He is our Protector.” So in Allah let the believers put their trust.
>
> <sup>[Quran 9:51](https://quran.com/9/51)</sup>

> To Allah ˹alone˺ belongs the knowledge of what is hidden in the heavens and the earth. And to Him all matters are returned. So worship Him and put your trust in Him. And your Lord is never unaware of what you do.
>
> <sup>[Quran 11:123](https://quran.com/11/123)</sup>

So as these verses express, only what Allah wills is allowed and that we, as Muslims, put all our trust in him. And we especially do not put our trust in inanimate objects that have no soul, being, and power.

#### Breaking down the Logic

Did the Sahaba fight with their bare hands in the battles? No, and this applies to your question.

Let me break down the logic, you're using the crate/tools as an extension of yourself ultimately, so those crates that you use to protect yourself from the shark are used instead of your arms. So in this situation, the crate is recognized in not having any power on its own, only when it is wielded and depending on how it is used. In some hands, a tool is not dangerous, but in other hands, the tool can be dangerous.

But the nazar eye isn't used as an extension of anyone's self, it's not used as a tool. It is generally used as if the object itself has power which we know that inanimate objects can't do anything on their own and have no power. So what would be the difference in believing an idol has power and this nazar blue eyed object has power? Nothing. One could try to counter-argue and say that they don't believe the nazar is god but shirk isn't only limited to believing something else is god, but prescribing what only god can do to anything other than god. Not to mention there is no credible evidence in Quran and Sunnah supporting even the existence of the nazar eye.

> O humanity! A lesson is set forth, so listen to it ˹carefully˺: those ˹idols˺ you invoke besides Allah can never create ˹so much as˺ a fly, even if they ˹all˺ were to come together for that. And if a fly were to snatch anything away from them, they cannot ˹even˺ retrieve it from the fly. How powerless are those who invoke and those invoked!
>
> <sup>[Quran 22:73](https://quran.com/22/73)</sup>

Comment: As far as i understood, it is permissible. Am i right?

Comment: In this situation, believing the sharks are less likely to harm you due to the crates is not shirk because of the attitude and view you have towards those crates, viewing them essentially as tools for protection.